# Guidance for database involving pdf and word files

Tags: database-design

First, many thanks for any guidance on my query. I am new to making a database and as such have little idea how to achieve what I envisage.

I work in mathematics education and would like to compile a database for all the questions that I use to teach students. The questions are currently saved individually in pdf or doc files. The worked solutions to these questions are then stored as another pdf or doc file.

What would be the best way to organise and store all these question in a single searchable database? At present they are just in folders on my desktop and not easily accessible.

I would like an interface where I can use drop down menus to filer by topic, difficulty, teaching year etc and then display the options available. Would there then be a way of viewing each question, selecting the questions I would like and collating all these into a single word document template. i.e out of 10 questions for a particular topic, I view them all, choose 5 that I like and then have these 5 printed to a single word document template that I can issue to students?

This is probably a huge task and so please just any guidance where I can start and then go from there. Many thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The first step will be designing the tables that make sense for holding the shape of your data. But the second step will be actually pulling that data out of the PDFs and Word documents and inserting it into your database, which is more of a [StackOverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com) type of question. Thing like OCR and document parsers will probably be what you're after for that step.